# Finding the coefficients of the power series representation given a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Find the coefficients $a_k$ and the interval of convergence of the series: $f(x)=\frac{arctan(x)}{x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(2x+1)^k$

So far what I've tried is to get the series representation of $arctan(x)$ centered in $(x-\frac{1}{2})$ like this:
$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}+(x^2-\frac{1}{4})}=\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{4}{5}(x^2-\frac{1}{4}))}=\frac{4}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{4}{5}(-(x^2-\frac{1}{4})))^k=\frac{4}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{4^k}{5^k}(x+\frac{1}{2})^k(x-\frac{1}{2})^k$

However I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Oh also I can easily get a series representation of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(2x+1)^k$, but in that case I don't know how to incorporate the $arctan(x)$.

Comment: Seems to me you would want to consider the series as being centered at $x=-\frac12$ (where the variable part vanishes). Then maybe start looking at the value of $f,f’,f’’,\ldots$ there

Comment: I considered computing the derivatives of the function but they're way too complicated to compute a general $f^n$ formula, so I don't think that's the way of resolving the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Maybe you can compute the two series separately and multiply them to get what you want? Have a look at [this link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cauchy-product-of-power-series) for an example if you don’t know how to do this

Comment: Okaythis is good, problem now is obtaining the series for $arctan(x)$ in $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, every coefficient of $f^n(-\frac{1}{2})$ has the form $a(\frac{4^n}{5^n})$, where $a$ is a constant, my concern is that $a$ doesn't follow any clear pattern with respect to $n$ so I can't find a way of compacting the series in the sigma form.
Thanks.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to make it compact. You can for sure compute the first terms but there is no clear pattern for the coefficients.

Comment: Are you sure that the goal is not to find a good Taylor representation of the function for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ ?

Comment: I believe that the goal is to find the series representation in the form that was stated above, the interval will fall along, but my guess would be that it will converge for $|x-\frac{1}{2}|\le\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to make a partial fraction decomposition since the linear terms in the denominator are then easier to expand.

> We expand $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)$ at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and obtain
> \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx} \arctan (x)}&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{(1+ix)(1-ix)}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{1-ix}+\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{1+ix}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{2}-i\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}
>   +\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{i}{2}+i\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{\frac{2+i}{2}\left(1-\frac{2i}{2+i}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}
>   +\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{\frac{2-i}{2}\left(1+\frac{2i}{2-i}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}\\
>   &=\frac{1}{2+i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i}{2+i}\right)^k(2x+1)^k\\
>   &\qquad+\frac{1}{2-i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{i}{2-i}\right)^k(2x+1)^k\tag{1}\\
>   &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}\left(i^k(2-i)^{k+1}+(-i)^k(2+i)^{k+1}\right)(2x+1)^k\tag{2}\\
>   &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}\left((1+2i)^{k}(2-i)+(1-2i)^{k}(2+i)\right)(2x+1)^k\\
>   &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}
>   \sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}\left((2i)^l(2-i)+(-2i)^l(2+i)\right)(2x+1)^k\tag{3}\\
>   &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}
>   \left(2\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(2i)^l\left(1+(-1)^l\right)\right.\\
>   &\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \left.+i\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(2i)^l\left(1-(-1)^l\right)\right)(2x+1)^k\tag{4}\\
>   &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}
>   \left(\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{2l}2^{2l+2}(-1)^l\right.\\
>   &\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \left.+\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{2l+1}2^{2l+2}(-1)^l\right)(2x+1)^k\tag{5}\\
>   &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k+1}{2l+1}2^{2l+2}(-1)^l(2x+1)^k}\tag{6}
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we can make the geometric series expansion and get a wanted representation in the form $\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_k(2x+1)^k$. We make some further transformations/simplifications to get rid of the imaginary unit.
- In (2) we expand the terms of the series with the complex conjugate to obtain $\left(\frac{1}{2+i}\right)^{k+1}=\left(\frac{2-i}{(2+i)(2-i)}\right)^{k+1}=\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}(2-i)^{k+1}$ and similarly with the other part.
- In (3) we make a binomial expansion and collect the terms conveniently in the next step.
- In (4) we take even index $2l$ in the left-hand sum and odd index $2l+1$ in the right hand sum, since other indices do not contribute.
- In (5) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p+1}{q}=\binom{p}{q}+\binom{p}{q-1}$.

> In order to derive the series expansion of $\arctan (x)$ at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ we can integrate (6) termwise and set the constant term accordingly. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \arctan(x)&=-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
> +\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k+1}{2l+1}\frac{2^{2l+2}(-1)^l}{k+1}(2x+1)^{k+1}\\
> &=-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
> +\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{2l}\frac{2^{2l+2}(-1)^l}{2l+1}(2x+1)^{k+1}\\
> &=-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
> +\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{k}}\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{2l}\frac{2^{2l+2}(-1)^l}{2l+1}(2x+1)^{k}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

Expansion of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ at $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ is not that hard. We have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(2x+1)\right)}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(2x+1)^k\tag{8}
\end{align*}

> Finally multiplying (7) with (8) we get the desired expansion:
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\arctan(x)}{x+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty
> \left(\color{blue}{-2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(-1)^k}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.\color{blue}{+\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{5^m}\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{2l}\frac{2^{2l+3}(-1)^l}{2l+1}(-1)^{k-m}}\right)
> (2x+1)^k
> \end{align*}
> with the wanted $a_k$ marked in blue.

The radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{2}$ since the nearest singularity at the center $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ of the series expansion is $-1$.

Comment: This is amazing, I'd never have thought of doing a complex variable approach, thank you so much. Although I'd appreciate if you could explain a bit more what exactly did you do after (1).

Comment: @SergioGarciaCastro: You're welcome.

Comment: @SergioGarciaCastro: I've added the  missing sigma symbol in  (2)  and  the  following   line. Thanks  for pointing at  this mistake.  Is the  derivation clear   now?

Comment: @SergioGarciaCastro: You are heartily invited to upvote and/or accept answers. Upvotes indicate you find a post helpful. Accepted answers indicate you are satisfied with a given answer no longer waiting for additional support.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a bit better, althoug I still need more work on complex variable to fully understand whta you did after (1), but giving my answer with the imaginary unit is okay.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SergioGarciaCastro: Thanks for the credit and upvoting the answer. I've added some info which might be helpful.